# Rails 3.1 urllib2.quote(json.dumps(var)) Equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jsonp, urllib

In Python I can convert JSON into a useable encoded string eg:

```
cmd2 =  [{'cmd': 'inlinepush',
        'params': {'raw': 'score'
        }
}]

url = urllib2.quote(json.dumps(cmd2))

print url
```

This produces:

```
%5B%7B%22cmd%22%3A%20%22inlinepush%22%2C%20%22params%22%3A%20%7B%22raw%22%3A%20%22score%22%7D%7D%5D
```

I have searched and searched but not found a Ruby or Rails equivalent, particularly in the NET::HTTP library.

I really have spent a lot of time thrashing to no end and would be grateful of any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'json'

cmd2 = [{
  'cmd' => 'inlinepush',
  'params' => {
    'raw' => 'score'
   }
}]

puts CGI.escape(JSON.dump(cmd2))
```